# Why we have to pass parameters in main functions while sdl setup in Mingw?

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl

what is the use of these arguments ? 
Is there any other way also to run SDL without using parameters in main?

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me explain.

In usual program you can use one of two valid forms of `main`:

```
int main()

int main(int argc, char **argv) // arguments' names do not matter here
```

The difference between them is that second form allows your program to take command-line arguments.

---

But SDL uses a special `main` related hack.

SDL has `#define main SDL_main` somewhere in the headers.
Because of that, preprocessor will replace `int main(...)` with `int SDL_main(...)`.

Actual `main()` is located somewhere in SDL code. It does some initialization and then calls your "`main`" (which is `SDL_main`).

Actual `main()` may look like this:

```
extern SDL_main(int, char **);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // SDL initialization
    SDL_main(argc, argv);
}
```

It shows why you can's use `int main()`. SDL source has no prototype for `int SDL_main()` because C does not support function overloading. There can be only one prototype for `SDL_main` and SDL developers decided that it should be `int SDL_main(int, char **)`.

The reasons for this are clear: Many applications need to work with command line arguments. And many programmers are used to work with `int main(int, char **)` when they want to read a command line arguments.